# Link list on click display content on the right with header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to look into this subject, there is a lot of question around it, but i couldn't find a solution that fit what i would like to do.

**What i would like to do :**

I have a list menu on the left side et divs content area on the left. I also got a "header" on the top of them saying the name of the content selected.

I would like when clicked on one of the elements it show the the DIV with the content selected and also change the name of the header about the same content.

I would like that the FAQ div/content is selectect by default

PS: When a link is clicked i want the list element styling on the left different, background, color changed, should i use the :active element or focus ? and how can i integrate this in the js/jquery to follow up ?

**Problem faced :**

I've put some JS/Jquery that i got looking overalls the forums, but it doens't seems to works properly.

**EDIT :**

I've tried something with the code below.
The header and the content sync perfectly but since i've put a togglefunction for the link list on the left it somehow the toggle function doesn't kick in.
Any help or way to optimize this code is welcome, thanks for your time !
https://jsfiddle.net/Sadhill94/6ax4ym39/2/

Thanks everyone for your upcoming support and have a nice day !

```
<script>


  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
     $(document).ready(function() {  

      $(".copen").click(function() {

         $(".c").hide();

         var cid = $(this).data("c");
         $("#"+cid).show();   

      });

   });



    $(document).ready(function() {  

      $(".copen").click(function() {

         $(".d").hide();

         var kuk = $(this).data("d");
         $("#"+kuk).show();   
     });

   });

function toggleStyle(lu){
        var stylish= document.getElementById('menuList').children;
        for(var i = 0; i<stylish.length;i++){
            stylish[i].className ="inactiveStyle";

        }

        lu.className="activeStyle";
    }
</script>
<style>
*{
box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-wrap: break-word; 
}

#container{
    width:100%;
      } 

#box{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left:3%;
    padding-right:3%;
    padding-top:3%;
}

    .topOfThePage{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

.divSize{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align:center;
}

.leftAlign{
    width:20%;
}

.rightAlign{
    width:80%
}

/*.activeStyle{
           color:#fff;
    transition: 0.4s;
    background-color:#0f2c41;
    transition: 0.4s;
    }*/

    .inactiveStyle{
    border:2px solid #0f2c41;
    color:#0f2c41;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style: none;
        font-weight:500;
        font-size:1.1em;
        transition:0.4s;
    }

    .activeStyle{
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#0f2c41;
            border:2px solid #0f2c41;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style: none;
        font-weight:500;
        font-size:1.1em;
        transition:0.4s; 
    }


.row{
    display:inline;
}

.hideContent{
    display:none;
}

.leftAlign{
    display:inline-block;
}

.headerPres{
    display:inherit;
    width:inherit;
     padding-bottom:13%;
    color:#fff;
}
.h2Content{
    margin:auto;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:7em;
    padding-bottom:2%;
    padding-top:5%;
}

.pContent{
    padding-bottom:0%;
    padding-top:2%;
    font-size:1.5em;
}

.flag {
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; 
    background: #0f2c41;
    color: white;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    margin-bottom:3%;
    border:1px solid transparent; 
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.goTop{
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* FAQ CONTENT */
.accordion {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0f2c41;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-weight:500;
    width:40%;
    padding:1.5rem;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight:600;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(150,150,150);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(150,150,150);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(150,150,150);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=180, Color='#969696')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=180, Color='#969696');
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #0f2c41;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #0f2c41;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=180, rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=180, rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
    border-radius:5px;

}

.panel {
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    width:inherit;
    display:inherit;
    padding-left:7%;
    padding-right:7%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.panelP{
    text-align:justify;
    margin-bottom:6%;
    margin-top:1%;
    word-break:break-word;
    line-height: 1.7em;

}


.sizingCapt{
   padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    display:inherit;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    margin:0 auto;

}

/* SHOW AND HIDE CONTENT DIV CLASS*/

.menuPage{
    width:inherit;
    display: inherit;
}

.showContent{
    width:inherit;
    display:inherit;
}

#menuDivs{
    display:inherit;
}
```

```
    <div id="container">
        <a id="topOfThePage"><div id="menuDivs">
               <a class="topPage" type="hidden">
                <div id="d1" class="pageTitle flag d ">
<h2 class="h2Content">F.A.Q</h2>
<p class="pContent ">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
            </div>
           </a>

       <a class="topPage" type="hidden">
           <div id="d2" class="pageTitle flag d "style="display:none"><h2 class="h2Content">Termms & Conditions</h2>
                <p class="pContent">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
           </div>
       </a>       
        <a class="topPage">
            <div id="d3" class=" pageTitle flag d " style="display:none"><h2 class="h2Content">Delivery & Returns</h2>
                <p class="pContent">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
            </div>
        </a>
              <a class="topPage">
            <div id="d4" class=" pageTitle flag d " style="display:none"><h2 class="h2Content">Privacy Policy</h2>
                <p class="pContent">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
            </div>
        </a>
              <a class="topPage">
            <div id="d5" class=" pageTitle flag d " style="display:none"><h2 class="h2Content">Size Guide</h2>
                <p class="pContent">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
            </div>
        </a>
              <a class="topPage">
            <div id="d6" class=" pageTitle flag d " style="display:none"><h2 class="h2Content">Copyright</h2>
                <p class="pContent">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
            </div>
        </a>
              <a class="topPage">
            <div id="d7" class=" pageTitle flag d " style="display:none"><h2 class="h2Content">Credits</h2>
                <p class="pContent">Here you can find the frequently asked questions. We help you find an answer</p>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</a>

<div id="box">  
    <div class="leftAlign divSize">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="menuPage">
            <ul id="menuList">
 <a class="goTop" href="#" ><li class="activeStyle copen" data-c="c1" data-d="d1" onclick="toggleStyle();">F.A.Q</li></a>      
                        <a class="goTop" href="#" onclick="toggleStyle(this);return fasle;"><li class="copen inactiveStyle" data-c="c2" data-d="d2" >Terms & Conditions</li></a>
                        <a class="goTop" href="#" onclick="toggleStyle(this); return false;"><li class="copen inactiveStyle" data-c="c3" data-d="d3">Delivery & Returns</li></a>       
                        <a class="goTop" href="#" onclick="toggleStyle(this); return false;"><li class="copen inactiveStyle" data-c="c4" data-d="d4" onclick="toggleStyle(this);">Privacy Policy</li></a>
                        <a class="goTop" href="#" onclick="toggleStyle(this); return false;"><li class="copen inactiveStyle" data-c="c5"data-d="d5" onclick="toggleStyle(this);">Size Guide</li></a>
                        <a class="goTop" href="#" onclick="toggleStyle(this); return false;"><li class="copen inactiveStyle" data-c="c6"data-d="d6" onclick="toggleStyle(this);">Copyright</li></a>
                        <a class="goTop" href="#" onclick="toggleStyle(this); return false;"><li class="copen inactiveStyle" data-c="c7"data-d="d7" onclick="toggleStyle(this);">Credits</li></a>


                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="rightAlign divSize">
            <div class="sizingCapt">
               <div id="c1" class="c">
                    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="panelP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        </div>

                    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="panelP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        </div>

                    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="panelP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        </div>

                    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="panelP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        </div>


                    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="panelP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        </div>



                    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <p class="panelP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                        </div>

                </div>

           <div id="c2" class="c" style="display:none"> 
              <p>Cpmtemt 2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="c3" class="c" style="display:none"> 
                <p>Content 3</p>
            </div>
            <div id="c4" class="c" style="display:none"> 
                <p>Content 4</p>      
            </div>
            <div id="c5" class="c" style="display:none"> 
                <p>Content 5</p>
            </div>
            <div id="c6" class="c" style="display:none"> 
                <p>Content 6</p>
            </div>
            <div id="c7" class="c" style="display:none"> 
                <p>Content 7</p>       
            </div>
```

Comment: I dont understand exactly wha you are trying to achieve, can't you just add a div with your content, then .toggle() in jquery so it shows up ?

Comment: The problem, i don't know much about jquery, i could apply the div showing correctly but what about the top header changing aswell ?

Comment: jquery lets you either change the html of the header, or add classes to your elements, you can also set class="hidden" for example then with jquery you replace the class="hidden" by class="show"  with display:none and display:block in your css for example

Comment: Ok but i have more than 2 divs how is it gonna sync between the divs selected and also the header please ?

Comment: you can get 36 divs if you want you just have to add classes so you can recognize them, play with it and read the jquery doc you'll sort it out pretty quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I can't comment since i don't have enough rep yet, but i'm just gonna leave a rough idea here as my answer**

First you should find a way to tie these 3 different parts that make up the whole layout, so in your case links on the left, header and the content.

*Idea: add an attribute to each of these elements `data-id="faq"` this way you know that this link-header-content all belong to faq ID.*

Once you have a mean of identifying which content/header belongs to which link, only thing you need to do is listen to the clickEvents, grab the `data-id` of the clicked element, use that ID to find both header and content that belong to that ID and show them, make sure to hide the rest of the content.